# How to control power to USB ports using batch

Tags: windows-8, usb, batch, windows-8.1, power

How can I toggle the power to a USB port on/off using batch or the command line? I am using Windows 8 to do this. Does anyone know what I could do? I have 4 USB ports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need external hardware, such as a USB controlled relay. Windows itself does not provide a API or option to allow the power pins of USB ports to be switched off. This has been answered [previously here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404097/windows-power-off-an-usb-device-in-software) and [summarized history here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246077/controlling-simple-relay-switch-via-usb).

Comment: This doesn't use batch or command line.

Comment: Depending on the means of control, it could. Still, it's not possible as is. USB ports cannot be switch off. There's simply no such facility.

Answer (score 5):

**Analysis of the problem**

Since Vista, USB devices remain powered-on even after they are safely removed.

The Microsoft article
[USB Port Remains Active for Disabled or Safely Removed USB Device](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2401954)
describes this new behavior :

> In Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, when a USB device is marked as
>   Removed, the USB hub port to which it is connected is Disabled. When
>   the port is Disabled, no further USB traffic is sent to the device.
>
> In Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows Server
>   2008 R2, when a USB device is marked as Removed, the USB hub port to
>   which it is connected is not Disabled.

I believe this behavior is what you are trying to change, in order to power-down
devices that you have removed.

**Solution**

Power-down cannot be done via a batch script,
but it can be returned to its XP behavior by modifying the registry,
either as global setting for all USB devices or per-device.

> **To apply the workaround globally for all enumerated USB devices**,
>  add a
>   REG_DWORD value named `DisableOnSoftRemove` that has a value of 1 to
>   the following registry subkey:
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\usbhub\HubG`.
>
> **To apply the workaround for a specific device**, 
> add a REG_DWORD value
>   named `DisableOnSoftRemove` that has a value of 1 to the following
>   registry subkey:
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\vvvvpppprrrr`
>   where vvvv is the device's Vendor ID, pppp is the device's Product ID,
>   and rrrr is the device's Revision number (found in Device Manager).

Answer (score 2):

There is a [powershell module](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388) that you can use to e.g. [disable devices](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction.aspx).

With this you could stop the operating system from using the USB ports. But this doesn't kill the power supply to these ports. Because that is *in general* not possible without modifying the hardware.

Only shutting down the computer *might* cut the power. Some computers have [sleep-and-charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Sleep-and-charge_ports) ports. Those provide power even if the computer is switched off (as long as there is a mains connection or a battery with sufficient charge available).