# Control Power To Multiple USB Devices

Tags: usb, power, camera

**Problem**

I have multiple USB devices, (multiple power-only lights, a power & serial-data camera) that I need to control power to *programmatically* through a single USB port.

**Questions**

What hardware device options are available for this application?

What would such a device be called?

Is my need fundamentally flawed in that it's not possible?

Comment: Its possible, [I use software that allows device power off](http://safelyremove.com/features.htm) after safely removing it in Windows. Not sure how they do it but proves it is possible. Scroll to bottom of link page.

Comment: Based on [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/715888/how-to-control-power-to-usb-ports-using-batch) you will need an external source of control

Answer (score 2):

It seems the device is called either:

- Switchable USB Hub
- Programmable USB Hub

I'm looking for a similar thing myself and so far have come across:

01)  [YKUSH Yepkit USB Switchable Hub](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush) (€29.94)

> Want to switch ON and OFF your USB devices? With YKUSH you can
>   selectively control the power ON and OFF of the USB devices connected
>   to it... or you can just use it as a "normal" USB hub.

Straightforward tutorial for YKUSH is here:  ([Linux](https://www.yepkit.com/learn/hookup-guide-ykush)) ([Windows](https://www.yepkit.com/learn/hookup-guide-ykush-windows)).

02)  [Computer Controlled Switchable USB Hub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB004FwYhu0) (29 second video)

03)  [Acroname Programmable USB Hub with 4 Charge Ports](https://acroname.com/products/s77-usbhub-2x4-0?sku=S77-USBHUB-2X4) ($300)

Hopefully others can contribute some affordable, easy to implement and manage, solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an external controller for such a task.  My first idea would be to get an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/), Breadboard, and a USB hub and basically create a switch that is controlled through the Arduino.  The Aruduino would need a program called [Firmata](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Firmata) loaded onto it that allows for pin control over serial (USB).  Your program on the computer itself would run like this:

Turning USB hub off:

1. Eject Camera/Other Data devices connected to hub
2. Communicate with Arduino over Firmata and turn off necessary pins

Turning USB hub on:

1. Communicate with Arduino over Firmata and turn on necessary pins

And your circuit flow chart would look something like this:

```
USB Hub>USB Cable>Breadboard Switch/Arduino>USB Cable>Computer
```

The only disadvantage here would be that you can not individually switch off each USB device.  To achieve this you would need a fairly more customized solution that would involve building your own USB hub.  That would be an awesome project though!

Comment: Note: An arduino can only supply a few mA (20mA continuous) per pin. This is barely enough for a few LEDs and even a mouse or keyboard will overload it. It is unavoidable to use a relay or transistor for switching the load.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy any cheap USB hub that supports per port power switching, and use utility ***uhubctl*** to control power per port - read more at https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl. Some compatible hubs cost as low as $20.