# How to disable a USB port

Tags: windows-7, usb, power

For our RF Test Positioner System ([illustrative example](http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2014/04/satellite_inside_hertz/14473622-3-eng-GB/Satellite_inside_HERTZ.jpg)) I need to add a software-controlled fan. I would like to add a fan like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7M03GA5359&cm_re=USB_Fan-_-00-995-143-_-Product) and simply turn off it's USB-power to turn the fan on & off.

**Need**

- A method to turn the USB source power for this fan on and off

**Question**

- How can you disable the power of a USB port? Is there special USB hubs or devices?

  - I have found [mechanical switches](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6RP3720059&cm_re=usb_on_off-_-9SIA6RP3720059-_-Product), but I am looking for software-controlled! :)

**Target System**

- Window 7 Enterprise

Comment: It is going to be very hard for people to provide you with valuable information without knowing what operating system you're using.

Comment: Linux link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux

Comment: Windows link http://superuser.com/a/720313/285900

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control power to USB ports using batch](http://superuser.com/questions/715888/how-to-control-power-to-usb-ports-using-batch)

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's [this thing](https://acroname.com/products/s77-usbhub-2x4-0), a software controlled USB hub:

> Software controlled USB hub with 2 host (upstream) connections and 4 fast-charging (2.5A) device (downstream) connections. Control data, power and current limits separately. Boost USB signal levels to account for difficult interconnection environments.

Then there's [this board](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush):

> YKUSH boards allow the user to selectively switch ON and OFF each of the USB devices connected to the Hub downstream ports. The control is done using an application in the host system (e.g., PC to which the YKUSH board is connected). Switching ON/OFF a YKUSH downstream port with a device connected to it has the same effect than physically Connecting/Disconnecting a Device to a port of a typical USB hub.

Comment: Thank you Ouroborus. Ordered one of the Yepkit USB Switchable Hub (YKUSH) today, I'll post up the results here once it comes on!

Comment: I got my Yepkit, got it working and installed into our test system at work. This thing rocks!!!

Here is my working code, I simply use BAT file calls from the command prompt to turn em on and off. This also includes a LabVIEW example wrapper
 - (example) https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqpvojkpnzqaezv/Yepkit%20-%20example.zip?dl=0

Comment: @J-Dizzle Can you post the code to GitHub or something? Download link is dead.

Comment: Here is the code, and some Yepkit ref docs - http://justinreina.com/misc/yepkit/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the info on the [Yepkit YKUSH Switchable Hub](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush) Ouroborus, that looks exactly correct!! I also found the following solutions, stored here for future investigators :) -

[Pintant](http://pintant.cat/2012/05/12/power-off-usb-device/)

> They “broke” a USB cable, got the red inner-cable to pass through the relay. Then using one USB port I control the relay and I can switch on and off the other USB device.

[powerUSB](http://www.pwrusb.com/)

> The four outlet power strip is designed for end users in mind for Automation, Power Saving and Remote Computer monitoring. The three of the four outlets are controlled through the software. In addition to conserving power, the unit allows users to control devices, appliances and lights through their computer. The money spent on PowerUSB is paid back within a months by savings in electricity bills. In addition, this power savings reduce the CO2 footprint on earth.
>
> The PowerUSB has built in current sensor, making it a Power Meter to measure the power consumed by the attached devices.
>
> The digital IO version of the power strip adds the input/output option to the basic model. The input from sensors can be programmed to switch on a motor or a light through the controlled power outlet. The output can be programmed to generate a clock pulse or switch on digital devices programmatically. The attached computer sees the digital input/output through the USB interface.
>
> The watchdog version **PowerUSB-watchdog** monitors the attached computer/router for a timed heartbeat. This heartbeat is sent from an application in the computer. When the computer locks up for any reason, the heartbeat sent from the computer will stop. At this time the PowerUSB switches off and power resets the computer thus rebooting the computer/router. This feature is useful for remote computers and servers that need to be available on continuous basis.
>
> The **smart standalone model** offers the functionality of power control without tied to the computer. The standalone power strip can be programmed by connecting to computer. The on times can be programmed for daily or weekly times. The attached peripherals can be switched off during non working hours. The LCD display shows the power consumed through the power strip.