# Win 10 automatically reconnect Bluetooth on startup

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have bought a USB Bluetooth to keep my phone and tablet unlocked when at home.
It works absolutely fine, but I have to manually go into the action center every time after a reboot and turn the Bluetooth off and back on again in order for my devices to reconnect and unlock.

Is there anyway to automate this process?

(This suggested solution [How to toggle Win10 bluetooth off and on at startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1381354/how-to-toggle-win10-bluetooth-off-and-on-at-startup) seemed promising but the answer is a .ps1 script to turn Bluetooth on/off from the command prompt, but it doesn't say how to actually automate the process)

Thank you!

Comment: Thought I had the problem solved by just going to gpedit.msc and adding the script to the Startup process, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the RadioControlCmd app from the [windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/radiocontrolcmd/9pjbrhtbvnmr?activetab=pivot:overviewtab.) and create yourself a .bat file like so:

```
@ECHO OFF
radiocontrol.exe 0 OFF
radiocontrol.exe 0 ON
```

Then use the task scheduler to create a task and run the .bat file at startup.
It's REALLY straightforward!